# Difference between -volume and -volumes-from in Docker Volumes

Tags: docker, docker-volume

What is the exact difference between the two flags used in docker volume commands `-v` and `--volumes-from`. It seems to me that they are doing the same work, consider the following scenario.

First lets create a volume named `myvol` using command:

```
$ docker volume create myvol
```

Now create and run a container named `c1` that uses `myvol` and get into his bash:

```
$ docker run -it --name c1 -v myvol:/data nginx bash
```

Lets create a file `test.txt` in the mounted directory of the container as:

```
root@766f90ebcf37:/# touch /data/test.txt
root@766f90ebcf37:/# ls /data
test.txt
```

### Using `-volume` flag:

Now create another container named `c2` that also uses `myvol`:

```
$ docker run -it --name c2 -v myvol:/data nginx bash
```

As expected, the new generated container `c2` also have access to all the files of `myvol`

```
root@393418742e2c:/# ls /data
test.txt
```

### Now doing the same thing with `--volumes-from`

Creating a container named `c3` using volumes from container `c1`

```
$ docker run -it --name c3 --volumes-from c1 nginx bash
```

This will result the same thing in `c3`:

```
root@27eacbe25f92:/# ls /data
test.txt
```

The point is if `-v` and `--volumes-from` are working the same way i.e. to share data between containers then why they are different flags and what `--volumes-from` can do that `-v` cannot do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The point is if -v and --volumes-from are working the same way i.e. to share data between containers

`-v` and `--volumes-from` are not working the same way, but with both of them you **can** share data between containers.

> what --volumes-from can do that -v cannot do?

E.g. it can connect to another containers volumes without knowing how volumes are named and you do not specify path. You are able to add suffixes to containers ID's, with permissions like `:ro` or `:rw`.
More details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) - *Mount volumes from container (--volumes-from)* section

The other question is *what `-v` can do that `--volumes-from` cannot do?*
E.g. it can mount named volumes, you can mount host directories or [tmpfs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/) (this one you  cannot share between containers). In `--volume-from` you cannot share data with host directly.

The conclusion is: the purpose of `--volume` is to share data with host. ([here you can find more use cases](https://docs.docker.com/storage/)).
The purpose of `--volumes-from` is to share the data between containers.
They both works nice together.